# Chess apps that provide a 3D view of the board and allow export of PGN

Tags: online-chess

I'm looking for an Android chess app that satisfies the following criteria:

- Provides a 3D view of the board and the pieces (required)
- Allows one to have an account, and invite friends to play matches online (required)
- Allows export of PGN (optional)

Could someone suggest such an app?

Comment: @SmallChess Does 'Real Chess' for Android work?

Comment: Download the app? I'm an iOS user. Sorry I don't know.

Comment: @SmallChess Oh well, I'll give it a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chess.com is probably one of the world's most popular online chess platforms. It has an app and a website (which offers many more features, such as a [beta 3D view](https://www.chess.com/blog/webmaster/new-3d-boards--so-much-more/)). In both, you can export game PGNs and have an efficient friends system in which you can challenge people to play. There are also many other beneficial features- free lessons from master players, tactics training, vision training and numerous drills to improve endgame play, as well as Stockfish analysis. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: This meets all the requirements! Thanks, I've accepted your answer, and upvoted it too!